# Using Java Producer library in android for Amazon Kinesis service

Tags: java, android, amazon-kinesis

we wanted to use amazon kinesis service to stream video from producer to consumer, so in the docs they had mentioned different producer libraries available. They have producer library for Java, android, c++, c. We wanted to do streaming from android device to kinesis stream so we had a look at android producer library but from the sample code we came to know that we require to use another amazon service Cognito to create user pool, identity pool and all.

So what we wanted was to stream from android device using only kinesis and no other amazon service. So since android support java, we wanted to know whether the Java producer library can be used in android since it doesn't use any other amazon service or even use C++ producer library for android?

Searched on web for this but there were no post related to this. So guys any help will be appreciated. Any reference will be really  really helpful. Please help.